# Existence and uniqueness of an elliptic equation coupled with a parabolic equation (mean curvature flow)

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde, existence-theorems

Given a parabolic equation on a simply connected smooth domain $\Omega(t)$ with boundary $\Gamma(t)$
$$
\Delta u = 1 \quad on \quad \Omega(t)
\\
\nabla u \cdot n + u = g \quad on \quad \Gamma(t)
$$
(where $g$ is a constant), coupled with a parabolic equation that controls the evolution of $\Gamma(t)$ (in this case mean curvature flow, but really any parabolic equation will do)
$$
V = \kappa + u \quad on \quad \Gamma(t)
$$
(where $V$ is the normal velocity, and $\kappa$ is the mean curvature).

Do you know of any good references for proving existence and uniqueness? This is somewhat similar to Hele-Shaw flows, but I can't find anything similar enough that I can get it working for this system.

Comment: Related (but not answered) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/100767/existence-of-pde-system-mean-curvature-flow-coupled-with-surface-pde

Comment: Related, but quite different, as they have two parabolic equations. The extra time derivative makes things a *bit* easier. The only methods I have found that *might* prove my problem involve regularizing it with a time derivative.